# Method of calculating $\int_0^{a}{\frac{f(x)}{b_i-f(x)}\,dx}$ for large set of different values of $b_i$ quickly

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

My aim is to compute the following integral over a large set of different values of constants, $b_i$, obtaining a set of values for $y_i$ (with the help of a computer and numerical integration):

$$y_i=\int_0^{a}{\frac{f(x)}{b_i-f(x)}\,dx}\qquad \text{for }i=1,2\dots n$$

$a$ is a known constant, and $f(x)$ is a known function, both of which do not vary throughout the computation.

If there are $n$ different values of $b$, it would seem that this would involve the calculation of $n$ different integrals: this will simply take too long for my program to calculate. Instead, it would be ideal to calculate a particular integral (that is independent of $b_i$) only once, and then calculate each $y_i$ using that single integral and the corresponding $b_i$ value.

For example, if the integral was instead as follows:

$$y_i=\int_0^{a}{\left(b_i-f(x)\right)\,dx}\qquad \text{for }i=1,2\dots n$$

Then the only integral that needs to be calculated throughout the entire computation is:

$$I=\int_0^{a}{f(x)\,dx}$$

Therefore, each value of $y_i$ can be determined using the following expression:

$$y_i = a \cdot b_i - I$$

Therefore, $n$ values of $y_i$ have been determine while only calculating a single integral, a lot quicker than having to do the computation by calculating $n$ different integrals.

So, my question is, can a similar technique be found for the integral at the start of this post? The main problem is trying to separate $b_i$ from the rest of the integral so that any integration becomes independent of $b_i$. So far, I've attempted setting $f(x)$ equal to $g'(x)$ in the hopes I'd come across something similar in spirit to:

$$\int{\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}\, dx} = \ln{\left|g(x)\right|}$$

I thought about substituting in a new variable $u=b_i - f(x)$ to simplify the denominator, but this seems to be no help as $u$ becomes a value that changes as $i$ changes.

Any help in this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless you know something special about $f(x)$ then this is way too general of a problem for us to be able to say something useful. You are pretty much asking for a fast way of solving a general integral that might or might not have singularities. (To see this: if $g(x)$ is any function and $b_j = b$ then take $f(x) = \frac{bg(x)}{1+g(x)}$ and your integral becomes $\int_0^a g(x){\rm d}x$)